# Is this type of table allowed in Bio.SE?

Tags: discussion

<kbd>`Table1`</kbd> <kbd>`Table2`</kbd> <kbd>`Table3`</kbd> 
<kbd>`Cell 1`</kbd> <kbd>`Cell 2`</kbd> <kbd>`Cell 3`</kbd> 
<kbd>`Cell 4`</kbd> <kbd>`Cell 5`</kbd> <kbd>`Cell 6`</kbd> 
<kbd>`Cell 7`</kbd> <kbd>`Cell 8`</kbd> <kbd>`Cell 9`</kbd> 
<kbd>`Cell 10`</kbd><kbd>`Cell 11`</kbd><kbd>`Cell 12`</kbd>

This type of table may not be seen in the mobile site as seen in the full site.

Can this type of table be advisable over `<pre>` when it is used to create a tabular format?

Comment: I would prefer the least amount of formatting. Use only what is necessary. This looks good but doesn't have any additional advantage. If you need good tables you can use LaTeX code too.

Comment: I have used a LaTeX table [in this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/38640/3340).